# html-webpack-plugin adding type attribute to script tag

Tags: html-webpack-plugin

Version 2.30.1

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Project',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        preserveLineBreaks: false
      },
      hash: true,
      template: './src/index.html'
    })
```

Results in:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js?d944356bf9245ce4bab5">
```

but should be:

```
<script src="bundle.js?d944356bf9245ce4bab5">
```

Either the configuration is wrong or missing something or this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

minify: { /* your props */, removeScriptTypeAttributes: true }

html-webpack-plugin 3.1.0

html-minifier 3.2.3

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.